# Courses In Advanced Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

This question is more of a resource question rather than actual math. I'm a 15 year old that for a long time has been very interested in formal higher level mathematics. Luckily my math teacher last year loves math as much as I do, and allowed me to borrow his notes from college math classes he took. My favorite area of higher level mathematics so far is by far Complex Analysis. I LOVE it.

Unfortunately, my math teacher never did anything more than a first course in Complex Analysis, and he doesn't know of anyway to help me pursue my interest in the subject.

I was wondering if any of you guys know of some online math websites with notes from a course in Advanced Complex Analysis, or perhaps knew of some free online courses I could take to pursue the subject. I already found some Youtube video lectures, but the man in them isn't very good at teaching the subject, and I'd really appreciate a different resource if possible.

Please give me any ideas, resources, or advice concerning finding such an archive on Advanced Complex Analysis. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder how would you cope with complex analysis, let alone advanced one, unless you already covered basic and advanced Calculus at least (recommended also at least a basic course in linear algebra). Have you?

Comment: Of course. I've covered Basic, Differentiable, and Integral Calculus, Linear Algebra, Abstract Algebra, Sequences and Series, and various topics in Number Theory and Graph Theory, as well as much more.

Comment: It would be helpful if we knew how far you had got in those topics (they are each very broad). Could you perhaps give an example of a "high point" in each of those courses, so we can see where they get to?

Comment: Well let's see, That's a pretty broad question Patrick Stevens. I've covered most of Calculus, and I don't know what else to say there. Derivatives, Antiderivatives, Definite Integrals, Improper Integrals, Arc Length, Green's Theorem, Stoke's Theorem, ... oh and I forgot to mention I've done a good bit of Multivariable Calculus as well, though not as extensively. I've done all of the basic tests for series convergence, limits (obviously), and concerning complex analysis ive gone over Cauchy's Theorem, isolated singularites, Residue Thm, Taylor and Laurent series. Residue Thm is where I leftoff

Comment: Try these from Cambridge University https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/IB/ComplexAnalysis/

Comment: Thanks David Quinn. I'll take a look at those.

Comment: Hmm. While obviously I haven't had a sufficent period of time to look over the page David sent me a link too, it looks like mostly stuff I've already covered. Any other links or resources would be appreciated.